# SQLite default value setting

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite administrator interface(0.8.3.2 public beta) in my windows XP PC. I am setting default value for some of columns(text,integer) in my table(like 0,'none' etc). But it seems some quotation marks will be added around the default values after i do some editing to the table each time(like 'none' will become '''none''' if i edit first time, then '''''none''''',it will add more and more quotes each time i do some modifications in table). Why is this happening? what to do to stop this? please help
Thank you

EDIT:I am directly editing the table using administrative inteface

Comment: Apparently, that program is buggy.